# open port programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, port

I am trying to create a program to open router ports, possibly in C#. I have heard that it is possible with the opennat C# library. I tried with this code but the program shows no answer signs.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    OpenPort().Wait();
}
private static async Task OpenPort()
{
    var nat = new NatDiscoverer();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
    var device = await nat.DiscoverDeviceAsync(PortMapper.Upnp, cts);

    await device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 11000, 11000, 0, "port 11000"));
}
```

Comment: NAT doesn't mean `router`.

Comment: Don't use `.Wait` in a winforms application to wait for a task to complete, it's going to deadlock. Most likely the `await nat.DiscoverDev...` method completed and then everything deadlocked because you blocked the processing that would handle this completion. Try removing the call to `Wait()` in the constructor and see what happens.

Comment: This code looks for any device that supports UPNP. Which may be your TV, your console, your phone, your local machine or none at all. It will then try to modify the NAT configuration for that random device. Not a good idea.

Comment: I usually use the Win32 library wlanapi library from the Windows System32 folder.  The source code is availble from www.pinvoke.net.  The libraries you are referring to are doing the same calls to wlinapi.dll that are shown at pinvoke.  The Net managed libraries did not implement all the IP Protocols and there is no way of modifying the c# code to add missing protocols.  You either need to do the modifications in c++ or call the Window dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of NatDiscovers using from here https://csharp.hotexamples.com/en/examples/Open.Nat/NatDiscoverer/-/php-natdiscoverer-class-examples.html

```
 public void OpenExternalPort(int privatePort, int publicPort, string description)
 {
     localHostPort = privatePort;
     var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30);
     var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeSpan);
     natDiscoverer = new NatDiscoverer();
     natDevice = natDiscoverer
         .DiscoverDeviceAsync(PortMapper.Upnp, cancellationTokenSource)
         .IsCompleted();
     mapping = new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, privatePort, publicPort, description);
     natDevice
         .CreatePortMapAsync(mapping)
         .IsCompleted();
 }
```

It seems like your code example (but  `new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, privatePort, publicPort, description);` doesn't contain one more zero, like in your code).

So, are you really understand the problem? Maybe you don't need to Port Map? Or maybe you have a problem in other parts of the system (like firewall)? How are you understand that your code not working?

Comment: maybe I got confused I didn't mean to open the nat but to forward the router ports so that library don't works for me